# How can I specify an editor when I run commands.executeCommand of vscode API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to fold regions in the editor with `vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.foldAll")` command. But it only works on the active editor. Is there a way to specify a target editor for it?

I tried `vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.foldAll", editor)` but I doesn't work.

I know I can make the editor active and then use the command, but I want it to work without activating the editor.

Comment: get a list of all open files, open the files one by one and execute the command

Comment: @rioV8  I want the current editor to be active when the command is running on other editor(s).

Comment: after you applied it to all files, open the file for the current editor in each group

Comment: it has to happen in the background with the current editor never loosing focus because it happens frequently

Comment: Probably no way to do what you want without doing what @rioV8 suggests.  Loop through the open editors with the `tabGroups` property, activating each and then do the current editor (which you saved a reference to) last.  If you want to see sample code for this approach, let us know.

Comment: @Mark I have already tried that approach before I asked the question here. But it does not seem suitable for the extension that I am working on

Comment: @Mark I'd really appreciate it if you could help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74932170/inserting-or-removing-a-line-inside-a-folded-region-causes-it-to-unfold